# In Memoriam: Akira Toriyama

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Akira Toriyama, creator of *Dragon Ball*, [died on March 1st, 2024](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-68444060), from an acute subdural hematoma. I can't say that I ever got terribly into *Dragon Ball*, but he had a huge impact on *shonen* anime.

Comment: So many days I can remember rushing home after school to watch the latest episode of Dragon Ball Z.. Defined several great years of my childhood.. RIP to one of the greats..

Comment: I liked Chrono Trigger. It may not be the most complex game ever, but it does carry you along for an adventure.

Answer (score 8):

He's now moved onto the [Other World](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Other_World).
[image]